# Gatsby Image in masonry has no height

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I've added a [masonry hook](https://janosh.io/blog/react-hooks-masonry) for my Gatsby site which is a gallery. Works great on mp4s and gifs, but when the item is a Gatsby Image, it has no height.

I can set a `height:500px`, `position:static`, and `img{object-fit:contain}` on `gatsby-image-wrapper`, but it's oddly proportioned.

I think this is happening because the rendered `img` from Gatsby Image is `position:absolute` with `object-fit:cover` so the masonry hook doesn't know what size it is, but I'm too beginner to figure it out.

Gatsby Image in the masonry item looks like:

```
<div class=" gatsby-image-wrapper" 
style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 900px; max-height: 613px;">
<div aria-hidden="true" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 68%;"></div>
<picture><source srcset="myImage.jpg 225w,
myImage.jpg 450w,
myImage.jpg 900w,
myImage.jpg 1310w" sizes="(max-width: 900px) 100vw, 900px"><img sizes="(max-width: 900px) 100vw, 900px" srcset="myImage.jpg 225w,
myImage.jpg 450w,
myImage.jpg 900w,
myImage.jpg 1310w" src="myImage.jpg" loading="lazy" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: center center; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 500ms ease 0s;">
</picture>
```

any help greatly appreciated, thanks